# Replicating nested mapping within a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling with mapping some data so I can properly display it.  I have an Object where I have removed a lot of data but the overall structure is like so

```
{
   "userData":[
      {
         "name":"something",
         "job":"something",
      }
   ],
   "bikeData":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "userId":1,
         "bikesResults": {
               "bike_technical":[
                  [
                     {
                        "speed":"28.3mph",
                        "gears":4,
                     }
                  ]
               ],
               "top_10_bikes":[
                  [
                     {
                        "name":"Bike1",
                        "values":3.5,
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"Bike2",
                        "values":5.4,
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"Bike3",
                        "values":9.8,
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"Bike4",
                        "values":4.3,
                     },
                  ]
               ],
               "bike_score":[
                  {
                     "quality":"7",
                     "price":"3"
                  }
               ]
         },
         "Something":1,
         "Somethingelse":0,
      }
   ],
}
```

So what I am interested in is the `bikeData` part, more specifically `bikesResults` and the `top_10_bikes`.  As `bikeData` is essentially an array of Objects, I used map.

```
bikeObject.bikeData.map((item, index) => {
  console.log(item.bikesResults);
});
```

So that console.log will output the data for `bikesResults`, so that seems to work.

The part I am struggling with is the next part, getting the data from the top 10 bikes.

I created an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8yej0scn/4/) to show how I got it working with plain Javascript.  With React however, I am struggling with the nested maps.  Currently I am trying something like this

```
{bikeObject.bikeData.map((item, index) => {
    return item.bikesResults.top_10_bikes.map((item2) => (
      { item2 }
    ));
  })}
```

And once again, I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvh8np2f/4/) to demonstrate.  As you see in this fiddle, in the console, I am getting errors, and not sure how I can even do the third map.

There is probably a better way to do this?  But my main goal is to within React, print out the data within top_10_bikes.

Any advice in achieving this appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/yfohLe5z/ (note that you need to map over `item.bikesResults.top_10_bikes[0]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h2>Data:</h2>
        {bikeObject.bikeData.map((item) => {
          return item.bikesResults.top_10_bikes.map((item2) => {
            return item2.map((item3) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <p>{item3.name}</p>
                  <p>{item3.values}</p>
                </div>
              );
            });
          });
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```